# What's wrong with my simple Java program?

Tags: java, primes

It's just supposed to print the prime numbers below 100 but it only gets the number '3' as an output. I'm only just starting to learn Java so it all looks right to me.

```
public class ClassesAndObjects {
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        Prime n = new Prime();
        for (int i = 3; i < 100; i++){
            n.Number = i;
            n.factors();
        }
    }

}

class Prime{
    long Number;
    long fact;
    boolean state = true;

    void factors(){
        for (fact = 2; fact < Number; fact++){
            if (fact != Number){
                if (Number % fact == 0){
                    state = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (state == true){
            System.out.println(Number);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: This must be one the worst prime number implementations in Java of all time.

Comment: I'm just starting. I have no idea what I'm doing yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to reset the boolean state to true at the beginning of each call, otherwise it's always false except for the first call (when i =3 )

```
void factors(){

    state = true;
    for (fact = 2; fact < Number; fact++){
        if (fact != Number){
            if (Number % fact == 0){
                state = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if (state == true){
        System.out.println(Number);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a statement like this:

```
    if (state == true){
        System.out.println(Number);
    }

    state = true; //reset the state variable
```

Here we are resetting the state variable to true for next iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you dont have state = true as default in your factor() method. So when it runs state = false for the first time (happens when Number = 4), then it is always false. Just add the bolded line in your code and you are good to go.

```
void factors(){
    **boolean state = true;**
    for (fact = 2; fact < Number; fact++){
        if (fact != Number){
            if (Number % fact == 0){
                state = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if (state == true){
        System.out.println(Number);
    }

}
```